# Implement jQuery Autocomplete plugin with source URL specified in element markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I am implementing [jQuery AutoComplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) like this:

HTML:

```
<input type='text' class='AutoComplete' url='/source/data'>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".AutoComplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/source/data"
});
```

Above code is working. Now I want that `source` part of Autocomplete option should be fetched from input's `url` attribute (`url='/source/data'`).

How is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the autocomplete() function (to set up the source), separately for each textbox.

```
function init(){
    $( ".autocomplete" ).each(function(ix,item){
       var $item = $(item),
           url = $item.attr('data-ac-url');
       $item.autocomplete({ source: url});
    });
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

This works with this HTML:

```
<input id='box1'
       class='autocomplete'
       value='' type='text'
       data-ac-url='/asp/autocomplete-src1.aspx' />
<input id='box2'
       class='autocomplete'
       value='' type='text'
       data-ac-url='/asp/ac-src2.php'/>
```

To specify the URL in the element markup, I recommend using an attribute like `data-???`, [which complies with the HTML5 standard](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Comment: +1 Thanks. Working perfectly. Can you please fix another thing. If there is not a `data-ac-url` property in element then it generates an error in firebug like `this.source is not a function`. Can we not fix it like that it do nothing if there is not a `data-ac-url` property.

Comment: Why not?  You could probably insert an `if` statement in there to test for that.  I wonder how you would do that?   hmmmmm.....